# pushdown predicate: can not be resolved against partition columns: []

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, dynamic-frameworks

An error occurred while calling o91.getDynamicFrame. User's pushdown predicate: column1='country-code' can not be resolved against partition columns: []

I am getting above error while trying to create a push_down_predicate for parquet file

`I tried using prddicate pushdown and optimize the code`